# Getting 404 for jupyterLab on jupyterHub

Tags: centos, jupyter, jupyterhub

So I'm trying to setup JupyterHub service with JupyterLab on it in production mode (Centos). For the simplicity, I have chosen system user authentication (PAM). So now I have several users with the ability to run individual servers. The problem is that I need to setup a JupyterLab so they could work properly.
I did everything (and probably a little more) jupyterhub docs tells to do:

1. Enable jupyterlab extension system-wide (`jupyter serverextension enable --py jupyterlab --sys-prefix`)
2. Added needded config option (`c.Spawner.cmd = ["jupyter-labhub"]`)
3. Some other useless stuff
   But the `/lab` url still returning 404 error.
   Related console output:

```
Jun 29 14:48:51 jupyter-infra-1 pipenv[11806]: Message: '404 GET /user/nataliya/lab (nataliya@::ffff:127.0.0.1) 57.16ms'                                
Jun 29 14:48:51 jupyter-infra-1 pipenv[11806]: Arguments: ()                                                                                           
Jun 29 14:48:51 jupyter-infra-1 pipenv[11806]: --- Logging error ---                                              
Jun 29 14:48:51 jupyter-infra-1 pipenv[11806]: Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                       Jun 29 14:48:51 jupyter-infra-1 pipenv[11806]:  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1681, in _execute
Jun 29 14:48:51 jupyter-infra-1 pipenv[11806]:    result = self.prepare()                                                                               
Jun 29 14:48:51 jupyter-infra-1 pipenv[11806]:  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/base/handlers.py", line 697, in prepare          
Jun 29 14:48:51 jupyter-infra-1 pipenv[11806]:    raise web.HTTPError(404)                                                                              
Jun 29 14:48:51 jupyter-infra-1 pipenv[11806]: tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 404: Not Found
```

Probably not related console output:

```
Jun 29 14:39:36 jupyter-infra-1 pipenv[11806]:    raise web.HTTPError(404, u'Kernel does not exist: %s' % kernel_id)                                    
Jun 29 14:39:36 jupyter-infra-1 pipenv[11806]: tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 404: Not Found (Kernel does not exist: d85c98fa-2998-4fb3-85e2-8dc6ecbd093a) 
Jun 29 14:39:36 jupyter-infra-1 pipenv[11806]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:                                     
Jun 29 14:39:36 jupyter-infra-1 pipenv[11806]: Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                      
Jun 29 14:39:36 jupyter-infra-1 pipenv[11806]:  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1081, in emit                                     
Jun 29 14:39:36 jupyter-infra-1 pipenv[11806]:    msg = self.format(record)                                                                            
Jun 29 14:39:36 jupyter-infra-1 pipenv[11806]:  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 925, in format                                   
Jun 29 14:39:36 jupyter-infra-1 pipenv[11806]:    return fmt.format(record)                                                                             
Jun 29 14:39:36 jupyter-infra-1 pipenv[11806]:  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/log.py", line 196, in format                     
Jun 29 14:39:36 jupyter-infra-1 pipenv[11806]:    formatted = self._fmt % record.__dict__
```

I'm out of any ideas, so would be appreciated for any.

Answer (score 0):

So, I fix this by installing jupyterlab package by pip3.
And this is how it was:

1. I tried to enable jupyterlab for a user with `/home/jupyterhub/.local/bin/pipenv run jupyter serverextension enable --py jupyterlab --user`
   but that return me exception:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyterlab'
> I re-checked that my Pipfile.lock includes a jupyterlab extension... and it was!
> 2. I tried to install jupyterlab with the most standart way:

`pip3 install jupyterlab`

And it did a thing!

Still not sure why the jupyterlab installed with pipenv didn't have result.